# Cannot show alert dialog in onStart

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to show an alert dialog when an exception at start up (if a web service call fails).

I have simplified it as much as I can

The code is as follows:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        // doWSCall();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetMessage("Test").Create().Show();
    }
```

The dialog is not shown, nothing appears in the debug output nor does anything appear in the device log.

Note this is Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a full AlertDialog : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Or if you show notify only, use Toast instead of AlertDialog

Toast here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: Thanks, but I ideally want to show an alert dialog, not a toast.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AlertDialog.Builder alert()
{
        AlertDialog.Builder myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myQuittingDialogBox.setTitle("your title");
        myQuittingDialogBox.setMessage("set Msg Here");


        myQuittingDialogBox.setIcon(R.drawable.yourimg);

        myQuittingDialogBox.setPositiveButton("yes"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            { 
                // your code here
                dialog.dismiss();   
            }   

        });

        myQuittingDialogBox.setNeutralButton("no"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
            //write your code here
                dialog.dismiss();
         } 
        });

        myQuittingDialogBox.create();
        return myQuittingDialogBox;

}
```

**calling**

```
AlertDialog.Builder diaBox = alert();
diaBox.show();
```